# Передача данных сервер node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Как реализовать в реальном времени передачу данных сервер сервер?

Использую node.js Express `Socket.io`, если поступает на 1 сервер команда, он отправляет её на второй сервер на выполнение. Как закончились вычисления, он отправляет обратно на 1  а там  на клиент.

Буду признателен за пример.

Comment: `npm install socket.io-client`. А дальше все как в браузере... Что конкретно у вас не получается сделать?

Answer (score 1):

У меня было нечто похоже, с клиентом посредством socket.io коннект, с другим сервером коннект через net, все работает. В примере не совсем сокет получился а как запрос фактически, но большего не требовалось

не самый лучший вариант, но допилите

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var net = require('net');

io.on('connection', function(browser){

  browser.on('browserEmit', function(request, callback){
    responseToClient(request,callback,browser.id);      
  });

  browser.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('disconnectBrowser');
  });

});

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, ip);
client.write(message.send(param.token, param.type, param.arg2, param.arg3, param.arg4));

client.on('connect', function(){
    connectErr='';
    console.log('Connected '+ip+':'+port);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        client.destroy();
    } 
});

http.listen(8888, function(){
  console.log("WebServer START: 8888");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

У NodeJs(начиная с 10.5.0) из коробки есть решение для распараллеливания сложных вычислений путём создания дополнительного потока.

[Документация](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html)

[Habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/415165/)

Думаю в вашем примере это решение подойдёт лучше.